# Split String In R Based On Character Location

Tags: r, strsplit

I'm trying to split these strings in R (column entries) into three separate columns:

```
João Moutinho Monaco, 30,  M(C) 
Clinton N'Jie Marseille, 23,  FW
Frederic Sammaritano Dijon, 30,  AM(LR)
```

to become

```
Player                Team           Pos
João Moutinho         Monaco         30,  M(C) 
Clinton N'Jie         Marseille      23,  FW
Frederic Sammaritano  Dijon          30,  AM(LR)
```

I can find the location of the characters using gregexpr and nchar, but but I'm not sure how to use strsplit for it. Or maybe another package is easier?

Comment: When did Oussama join the party?

Comment: Oops David, edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can read the vectors in to a `data.frame` with `read.csv` after creating a delimiter using `gsub`

```
read.csv(text=gsub("^(\\S+\\s+\\S+)\\s+(\\S+),\\s+(.*)", 
       "\\1;\\2;\\3", v1), sep=";", header=FALSE, 
       col.names = c("Player", "Team", "Pos"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#                Player      Team         Pos
#1        João Moutinho    Monaco   30,  M(C)
#2        Clinton N'Jie Marseille     23,  FW
#3 Frederic Sammaritano     Dijon 30,  AM(LR)
```

#### Update

If we have more patterns and the "Team" names have only a single word (i.e. before the first ',')

```
read.csv(text= sub("(\\s+[A-Za-z]+),(\\s+\\d+),(.*)", ";\\1;\\2\\3", v2), 
      header=FALSE, sep=";", col.names = c("Player", "Team", "Pos"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#                Player       Team         Pos
#1        João Moutinho     Monaco    30  M(C)
#2        Clinton N'Jie  Marseille      23  FW
#3 Frederic Sammaritano      Dijon  30  AM(LR)
#4       Angel Di María        PSG   28 M(CLR)
#5    Jean Michael Seri       Nice     25 M(C)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("João Moutinho Monaco, 30,  M(C)", "Clinton N'Jie Marseille, 23,  FW", 
                    "Frederic Sammaritano Dijon, 30,  AM(LR)")
v2 <- c(v1, "Angel Di María PSG, 28, M(CLR)","Jean Michael Seri Nice, 25, M(C)")
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful! However, I am having problems if the player has more than 3 or more words in his name. The whole string ends up in the first column (Player)... I've been trying to change the regular expression but to no luck.

Comment: @ClattyCake  Yes, it was specific to the pattern you showed.  I thought you had only a single pattern as the example showed only a single pattern

Comment: Ah right, it breaks down for character vectors like this: c("Angel Di María PSG, 28,  M(CLR)","Jean Michael Seri Nice, 25,  M(C)") , etc. 

Is there a way to change the regular expression so that if there are 3 or more words in a name then it'll recognise it in the player column? The team names will only have one string before the first comma (e.g. "PSG,", "Saint-Etienne", "Marseille") if that helps.

Sorry for the misinformation!

Answer (score 1):

The `word` approach from `stringr`,

```
library(stringr)
data.frame(Player = word(v1, 1, 2), 
             Team = sub(',','' ,word(v1, 3)), 
              Pos = word(v1, 4, 6), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#                Player      Team         Pos
#1        João Moutinho    Monaco   30,  M(C)
#2        Clinton N'Jie Marseille     23,  FW
#3 Frederic Sammaritano     Dijon 30,  AM(LR)
```